# Slow Login on Network Windows 7

Tags: networking, windows-7, slow-connection

I am trying to troubleshoot an issue where it takes a very long time (4-5 minutes) for users to log on to their computers on a network, and after catching this timeline with the Windows Performance Analyzer, I was wondering why there is a 203 second gap from where nothing seems to be running. Here is a screenshot of what I'm talking about.

[image: Screenshot]

The gap I'm talking about is from 220 to 420, where nothing seems to be happening. What would be a cause of this? My guess is that things like GPClient and SessionEnv might be crashing, because they seem to start, stop, and start again. I could not find too much info about what these items do on Google, and I have never dealt with this issue before. We do have a few Group Policies on the network when you log in, but those seem to be taking a normal amount of time. I'm concerned with that 200 second gap. Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: Check for DNS problems. Check if there are network drives mapped which are unreachable. Check network card settings (Autoneg/Duplex). Disable unused network cards (Wifi). Subnetting/multihomed DCs?

Comment: share the trace (if possible) and and I can take a look at it. Send the OneDrive/Dropbox link to  **my username {a T ] Ao L (D o T] c O m**